# One single-entry filter for all requests to all servlets

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, catch-all

I have many Servlets deployed on my server.

```
e.g. 
servlet1
servlet2
```

I also have filter: Filter, with the url pattern `"/*"`.

```
Filter catches all requests like localhost:8080/something except these ones localhost:8080/servlet1,localhost:8080/servlet2.
```

My question is following: How should i configure filter to catch all requests to all Servlets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is correct.

However, I guess in your case you deployed  your application as `someting.war`, so would only be able to catch requests to `http://localhost:8080/someting/*`, all the other requests won't go through your application.

So my guess is that you need to configure your container, to use your war as default reference.

Comment: I renamed and deployed my application as ROOT.war. Urls with any string (except servlet1,servlet2) goes thru my filter. So i need to configure?

Comment: I would suggest to clean ROOT, but if your application is loaded by default, than this is not the case. Your configuration is correct, maybe you have some specifics in your application, but /* must filter all Requests to the server.

Comment: no, it's just a regular filter which implements Filter. Filter does not catch requests to servlets, which have mappings thru their web.xmls. Is there anything like defaullt filter in tomcat? may be i need to configure that?

Comment: Well. I've configured default filter in catalina's web.xml. Now all requests go to my filter. But now one problem appeared. All requests to servlets are failing with "Not mapped" error. Requests are handled like this
    if(XYZ){handle} else {chain.doFilter()}.